# Incorrect Normal Map Lighting

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, lighting, love2d

I have a Love2D 3D rendering engine set up. Though I was able to get diffuse and specular map lighting working correctly, I haven't been able to get normal maps working.

[This is how my project looks with a point-light located at the camera position.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYo1D.gif)
I followed [this tutorial](https://shader-tutorial.dev/intermediates/specular-mapping/) for the shaders below, including the normal mapping section that has the lighting calculations in tangent space, though that resulted in a [weird split down my camera position.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pAQL.png)

The vertex tangents are calculated using [this tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Normal-Mapping) with triangulated faces. I also attempted manually sending vertex bitangent vectors to the vertex shader, but that resulted in a weird bug where lighting would [alternate between each triangle face](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TW3MA.png).

This is how I calculated the TBN matrix in the vertex shader:

```cpp
// VertexTangent and vertexNormal are passed in attributes.

highp mat3 modelViewMatrix_3x3 = mat3(viewMatrix * modelView);

highp vec3 VertexTangent = normalize(VertexTangent);
highp vec3 vertexNormal = vertexNormal; // Normalizing this causes the screen to turn black.
highp vec3 VertexBiTangent = cross(vertexNormal, VertexTangent);

tbnMatrix_viewSpace = modelViewMatrix_3x3 * mat3(
    VertexTangent,
    VertexBiTangent,
    vertexNormal
);
```

This is how I calculated lighting in the fragment shader:

```cpp
highp vec4 diffuseColor = Texel(diffuseTextureSampler, texture_coords);
highp vec4 normalColor = Texel(normalTextureSampler, texture_coords);
highp vec4 specularColor = Texel(specularTextureSampler, texture_coords);

highp vec3 normal_viewSpace = tbnMatrix_viewSpace * normalize((normalColor.xyz * 2.0) - 1.0);

highp vec4 lightPosition_viewSpace = viewMatrix * lightPosition_worldSpace;
highp vec3 lightDirection_viewSpace = normalize((lightPosition_viewSpace - fragmentPosition_viewSpace).xyz);
highp vec3 viewDirection_viewSpace = normalize(fragmentPosition_viewSpace.xyz - vec3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0));

highp vec3 lightColorIntensity = lightColor * lightIntensity;
highp float distanceFromLight = distance(fragmentPosition_viewSpace, lightPosition_viewSpace);

highp float diffuseStrength = clamp(dot(normal_viewSpace, lightDirection_viewSpace), 0.0, 1.0);
highp vec3 diffuseLight = (lightColorIntensity * diffuseStrength) / (distanceFromLight * distanceFromLight);

highp vec3 lightReflection_viewSpace = reflect(lightDirection_viewSpace, normal_viewSpace);

highp float specularStrength = clamp(dot(viewDirection_viewSpace, lightReflection_viewSpace), 0.0, 1.0);
highp vec3 specularLight = (lightColorIntensity * pow(specularStrength, specularLobeFactor)) / (distanceFromLight * distanceFromLight);

color.rgb = (diffuseColor.rgb * diffuseLight) + (specularColor.rgb * specularLight);
color.a = diffuseColor.a;
return color;
```

Comment: The way you calculate `tbnMatrix_viewSpace` looks suspicious. Can you try transforming each of the columns with `modelViewMatrix_3x3`, instead of multiplying the result?

Comment: @pezcode, I attempted doing this but it resulted in the same visual error I started with.

Comment: I figured out what was wrong! I calculated my VertexBiTangent's incorrectly before they were passed through to the shader. Though the lighting is mostly correct now, for some reason it's inversed, in the sense that the light becomes brighter the further away from the surface is.